# Formatting Date to get Date of a Specific format

Tags: java, date, formatting

I am trying to format Date to get a Date of a specific format. However it is not working. Don't know why! Here is what I did:

```
           for(LeaveApply leaveApply : leaveApplyList) {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                try {
                    leaveApply.setDate(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(leaveApply.getDate())));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

The output is :

```
LeaveApply [id=1, user=id [1]; loginName [admin], leaveType=Medical Leave, leaveTime=Half Leave, date=Fri Apr 15 00:00:00 IST 2011]
LeaveApply [id=0, user=id [1]; loginName [admin], leaveType=Weekend, leaveTime=Full Leave, date=Sat Apr 02 00:00:00 IST 2011]
LeaveApply [id=0, user=id [1]; loginName [admin], leaveType=Weekend, leaveTime=Full Leave, date=Sun Apr 03 00:00:00 IST 2011]
LeaveApply [id=0, user=id [1]; loginName [admin], leaveType=Weekend, leaveTime=Full Leave, date=Sat Apr 09 00:00:00 IST 2011]
LeaveApply [id=0, user=id [1]; loginName [admin], leaveType=Weekend, leaveTime=Full Leave, date=Sun Apr 10 00:00:00 IST 2011]
LeaveApply [id=0, user=id [1]; loginName [admin], leaveType=Weekend, leaveTime=Full Leave, date=Sat Apr 16 00:00:00 IST 2011]
LeaveApply [id=0, user=id [1]; loginName [admin], leaveType=Weekend, leaveTime=Full Leave, date=Sun Apr 17 00:00:00 IST 2011]
LeaveApply [id=0, user=id [1]; loginName [admin], leaveType=Weekend, leaveTime=Full Leave, date=Sat Apr 23 00:00:00 IST 2011]
LeaveApply [id=0, user=id [1]; loginName [admin], leaveType=Weekend, leaveTime=Full Leave, date=Sun Apr 24 00:00:00 IST 2011]
LeaveApply [id=0, user=id [1]; loginName [admin], leaveType=Weekend, leaveTime=Full Leave, date=Sat Apr 30 00:00:00 IST 2011]
```

As you can see the date is not in desired format (dd-MM-yyyy). Any help will be appreciable. 
The LeaveApply class is :

```
public class LeaveApply implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7223672229309295181L;
    private long id;
    private User user;
    private String leaveType;
    private String leaveTime;
    private Date date;

    public LeaveApply() {

    }

    public LeaveApply(User user, String leaveType, String leaveTime, Date date) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
        this.leaveType = leaveType;
        this.leaveTime = leaveTime;
        this.date = date;
    }    

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getLeaveType() {
        return leaveType;
    }

    public void setLeaveType(String leaveType) {
        this.leaveType = leaveType;
    }

    public String getLeaveTime() {
        return leaveTime;
    }

    public void setLeaveTime(String leaveTime) {
        this.leaveTime = leaveTime;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LeaveApply [id=" + id + ", user=" + user + ", leaveType=" + leaveType + ", leaveTime=" + leaveTime + ", date=" + date + "]";
    }    
}
```

And I am printing the list as :

```
for (LeaveApply leaveApply : leaveApplyList) {
        System.out.println(leaveApply);
}
```

Comment: i'm confused - you start out with a Date, convert it to a string, then parse it back into a date. Why? just use the original date, right?

Comment: What is the format of "leaveApply.getDate();"

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy thanks. I am doing this because all the dates are not in same format. Some of date is "E MMM dd 00:00:00 Z" and other is "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.0".

Comment: but leaveApply.getDate() returns a java.util.Date object right?

Comment: @Harry Joy I am not maintaining any format for the date property field of LeaveApply object, it is simple a Date type.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy yes it returns a Date object.

Comment: so you are going from java.util.Date to java.util.Date with unnecessary histrionics of formatting followed by parsing. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the SimpleDateFormat to format the string when you print it. What your code does now is:

- get a timestamp
- format it
- parse the formatted string back to a timestamp
- set the timestamp

Which is a rather expensive no-op, as a Date object only contains a long representing the timestamp, no formatting information.

Further on, where you print the timestamp, you use the default date format. You should use your date formatted at that point instead.

Answer (score 2):

Call `SimpleDateFormat.format(Date)` in your `LeaveApply.toString()` implemention for the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

As you format you will get the desired format in the String, as you parse it back you will get the Date object and it will execute `toString()` so you will always get the default format.